# In *nix, is there a practice for storing static libraries?

Tags: coding-style, packages

Lets say you are building an application that staticly links against libraries that you provide it. Where should you store these static libraries? Should you make a directory in the parent directory of your application called "libs" or "dependencies" and store it there? Is there a practice for doing this?

Comment: Read http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/resources/software_libraries.pdf, section 5, subsections 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I really liked your link the best here. TLDR, example.h in "include", libexample.a in "lib". It has thus far been the best tutorial I have seen thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux you have the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) defining conventions about files.

Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

Actually, I believe that you should prefer shared [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) to static ones.

Notice that a library makes mostly sense when it can be *reused* by *several* applications. Otherwise, it might not be worth making a library (e.g. for some code unique to your application).

If you have only *static* libraries, their location is specific to your build procedure, so don't matter much (you won't need any static library to run your executable). Of course it is very different for shared libraries.

If you need to embed or extend the Python interpreter (and this is not much related to static libraries), you should read the relevant [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html).

Comment: The reason why I need to use static libraries is because I am trying to build a snappy package. For example; The new ubuntu applications will not allow me to execute a python script using the installed (shared?) python interpreter. Ergo, I have to bundle my own interpreter if I want to execute python code. So as far as I know, static linking is the only way to do this, right?

Comment: The fact that the python interpreter is a shared library may have nothing to do with that.  It's more likely that, if such scripting is in fact not allowed, it's for security reasons.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just a quick question; If I embed a python interpreter into my program, does that necessarily mean I statically linked it?

Comment: @Akiva: No, not necessarily.  Program functionality remains the same, regardless of the linking choice.